# Set python path for Spark worker

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

What's the "correct" way to set the sys path for Python worker node?

Is it a good idea for worker nodes to "inherit" sys path from master?

Is it a good idea to set the path in the worker nodes' through `.bashrc`?  Or is there some standard Spark way of setting it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A standard way of setting environmental variables, including `PYSPARK_PYTHON`, is to use `conf/spark-env.sh` file. Spark comes with a template file (`conf/spark-env.sh.template`) which explains the most common options.

It is a normal bash script so you can use it the same way as you would with `.bashrc`

You'll find more details in a [Spark Configuration Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables).

Comment: Most people are looking to do something like this in spark-env.sh:


DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$DIR


And it does not work. Probably works if you push that to all worker nodes in some side-effect step. 

What is the run-time way of doing this through pyspark or spark-submit?

Comment: This conf setting does the trick in spark standalone: spark.executorEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName]

Answer (score 4):

By the following code you can change the python path only for the current job, which also allow different python path for driver and executors:

```
    PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/home/user1/anaconda2/bin/python PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/anaconda2/bin/python pyspark --master ..
```

Answer (score 2):

You may do either of the below -

In config,

Update `SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`, add below lines:

```
# for pyspark
export PYSPARK_PYTHON="path/to/python"
# for driver, defaults to PYSPARK_PYTHON
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="path/to/python"
```

**OR**

In the code, add:

```
import os
# Set spark environments
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = 'path/to/python'
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = 'path/to/python'
```

Answer (score -3):

The error of my case was that:

> Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.6 than that in
>   driver 2.7, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions

The solution that helped:

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python2.7
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python2.7
jupyter notebook
```

Of course, I installed python2.7 locally on workers.
I suppose it is also important that I also set the PATH.
I did not rely on local workers' settings. The path was inherited from setting the edge node where is jupyter-notebook.